# How can I link a JavaFX object to an object in my project?

Tags: java, javafx

I am new at Java and JavaFX.

I actually try to simulate a tree. Java looks good for that. 
A tree is defined by its root which a treenode. Each treenode have children (a treenode without child is a leaf).

I designed the methods to had children, save and restore a tree using the console. No problem.

Next step, was to draw a window and inside a pane as many FXML object as my nodes.
Question is: how do I associate a button with a tree-node, so that when I click a button I can get back to my tree-node?

I tried to use bt.setUserData(TreeNode node) but I can't recover it when using a mouse event handler

> ```
> @FXML protected void clicDessin(MouseEvent event) throws IOException {
>  //   teh anchorpane xhere I want to throw some information about my tree-node
>     AnchorPane arbre = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("noeud.fxml"));
>     Noeud n = ?????
>     AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(arbre, 0.0);
>     AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(arbre, 0.0);
>     ((Pane) Main.root.lookup("#pdt")).getChildren().add(arbre);
>     ((TextField) arbre.lookup("#nomnoeud")).setText(n.getNom());
>     ((TextArea) arbre.lookup("#descnoeud")).setText(n.getDesc());
> }
> ```

Of course clicDessin is the method associated to a click on the mouse for my button.

Any help appreciated. 
Please stay as simple as possible. I am not a Java warrior, neither english speaker.

Comment: What do you mean by "get back to my tree-node"?

Comment: I meant that I wanted to create a link between a custom object and its graphical representation. The goal is to be able to show/modify all the properties of the custom object by clicking its graphical view. I think I found the answer by creating a new class that inherits from Parent JavaFX class and implement a custom object (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer and it was pretty obvious, sorry.
I post the answer in case somebody needs it.

To position shape in a pane or scene, all I need is add a child. 
If I need a link between a custom object and a child, all I have to do is create a new class extending Parent that exposes a custom object as a property (public is mandatory if I want this property to be visible).

So I create a class DrawTreenode

```
public class DrawTreeNode extends Parent {
public TreeNode monNoeud;
private double x, y, h, l;
Rectangle fond = new Rectangle();
Label l1 = new Label();
Label l2 = new Label();
```

a basic method that implement event handler

```
public DrawTreeNode(TreeNode n, double posX, double posY, 
double largeur, double hauteur)
{
    TreeNode = n;
    x = posX;
    y = posY;
    h = hauteur;
    l = largeur;
```

JavaFX objects can be modified according to TreeNode properties

```
    l2.setText(String.valueOf(TreeNode.numChildren()));
    l2.relocate(x+10, y+15);
    this.getChildren().add(l2);
```

and I can implement event handler that refers (or at least accesses) my custom property

```
    this.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler() {
        public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
            appuyer();
        }
    });

}
```

Here, it uses properties of the custom object

```
public void appuyer() {
    AnchorPane arbre = null;
    try {
        arbre = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("noeud.fxml"));
        ((Pane) Main.root.lookup("#pdt")).getChildren().add(arbre);
        ((TextField) arbre.lookup("#nomnoeud")).setText(monNoeud.getNom());
        ((TextArea) arbre.lookup("#descnoeud")).setText(monNoeud.getDesc());
        ((TextField) arbre.lookup("#numfils")).setText(Integer.toString(monNoeud.numEnfants()));
        ((TextArea) Main.root.lookup("#txtaide")).setText("Cliquer pour voir/modifier le noeud.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

and I can add GraphTree (basically a custom JavaFX shape) anywhere in my project in any Pane using javaFX add method of standard class Shape.

```
((Pane) Main.root.lookup("#grille")).getChildren().add(new DrawTreenode(((Treenode) element),
                        calculX(((Treenode) element), largeurcell), calculY(((Treenode) element), hauteurcell),
                        largeurcell, hauteurcell));
```

I tried to translate my example in english as much as possible. I hope it could help.